# Redirect .php to no .php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this in my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Which will allow people to access `server/login.php` as just `server/login` but how can I make it so that if `server/login.php` is entered into the address bar it will redirect to `server/login`.

My site is getting different hits rather than just for one url because of this issue, thanks for your effort and time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an external redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1 [R,L]
```

The R-flag is a temporary redirect. If things work as you expect them to work, you can use R=301 to make it a permanent redirect. See [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for more information.

Edit: With your current rule, this will create an infinite loop. If you are running Apache 2.3.9 or later, use the END-flag on your internal rewrite rule. If you are unwilling or unable to use such a version of Apache, you can use the "THE_REQUEST" trick to stop an infinite loop, as this will only match if the request comes from outside:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)\.php[\s\?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your base path `RewriteBase /path/`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /path/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```